# How to programmatically launch mobility center (MBLCTR.EXE)

Tags: vba, vb6, powerpoint

Short version:  I can launch Windows Mobility Center (MBLCTR.EXE) from a command prompt, but cannot get it to launch via SHELL from VBA.

On a Win 7/64-bit laptop, from a command prompt in pretty much any directory on the system, I can enter MBLCTR or MBLCTR.EXE and the mobility center launches.  Handy thing, so I'm trying to build it into one of my add-ins. For just about any other app, I can do:

```
Shell "someapp.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

But

```
Shell "MBLCTR.EXE", vbNormalFocus
```

gives me a File Not Found error message.  Same thing if I leave off the .EXE, same thing if I supply the full path to the file (which works if I do it from a command prompt).

Same thing is true on my desktop if I've made the necessary reg change to allow MBLCTR to run; it's normally disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a good friend, an answer:

Instead of using SHELL "mblctr.exe" or the full path, use:

```
SHELL "c:\windows\Sysnative\mblctr.exe"
```

(substituting the correct local value for c:\windows of course)

On a 64-bit system, a 64-bit version of MBLCTR.EXE lives in System32, but when called from a 32-bit app, the call is redirected to SysWow64, but there's no MBLCTR.EXE in that directory, hence the File Not Found error.